# jQuery DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Why I'm getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

I respect the DataTables requirements (and I also read another topics about my error and I respect every answer and solution). Please help me.

Here is my php code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="table-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes"/>
                </th>
                <th>
                     Utilizator
                </th>
                <th>
                     Nume complet
                </th>
                <th>
                     Clasa
                </th>
                <th>
                     Functia
                </th>
                <th>
                     E-Mail
                </th>
                <th>
                     Ultima logare
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?
               foreach($data["users"] as $student)
               {
            ?>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <? echo $student["username"]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <? echo " ".$student["last_name"]." ".$student["first_name"].""; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <? echo getclass($student["class"]); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <?
                     $functie = 0;
                     if($student["role"] == 1)
                     {
                         $functie = 1;
                         echo "Administrator site";
                     }
                     if($student["fctsc"])
                     {
                         $functie = 1;
                         echo "Director";
                     }
                     if($student["diriginte"])
                     {
                         $functie = 1;
                         echo "Diriginte";
                     }
                     if($student["profesor"])
                     {
                         $functie = 1;
                         echo "Profesor";
                     }
                     if($functie == 0)
                         echo "Elev";
                     ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="mailto:<? echo $student["email"]; ?>">
                        <? echo $student["email"]; ?>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                     <? echo $student["lastlogin"]; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?
               }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: you need to post how you are initializing dataTable!!

Comment: No, I don't need. Cause, if I create another <table> without php codes, just html, everything works fine. The problem is in that code.

Comment: The problem will be in your dataTable initialization!! You must have written somewhere like this `$("#sample_1").dataTable();` Post that part!!

Comment: @Maurice have you checked that final (shown in browser) `<table>` is correct/valid one? Mix of PHP and HTML is not really helpful - post example of final HTML.

Comment: Yes, is a correct one, full HTML source code is here: http://pastebin.com/X25zgTVW

Comment: How does your script looks like? I think of the dataTables initialisation.

Comment: show your jquery script for the table

Comment: Need jquery code to check this. well why r u using  $functie .. just use switch or ifelse ... and else in end ...

Comment: which version of datatables and jquery are you using?

Comment: Without your js code its a bit of a guess, but the last few times I saw this error it was due to making a call to a column that is present. Say your table has five column and you call to the sixth column. But with out js, this is only a guess..

Answer (score 0):

check weather or not all the php echo's are actually outputting something that is not 'NULL' on all rows as DataTables will treat any cell with just NULL as content as non existant and this can also cause that error.
try avoiding direct php output to html table.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs for two reasons:

- Missing table header.
- Number of `td` elements in the table body differs from number of `th` elements in the table header.

However your HTML code seems to have correct number of columns, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/vLLb769f/).

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: Cannot read property ‘mData’ of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-mdata-of-undefined) for more information.